# What do these two lines means?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. Please help me with these two lines of code, I have to fix an issue. Explain these two lines:

```
JSON=$CURRENTFILE=$NEWFILENAME
echo $JSON > ${PROD_HOME}/tempHashes
```

Comment: first line: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=JSON%3D%24CURRENTFILE%3D%24NEWFILENAME and second line: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+%24JSON+%3E+%24%7BPROD_HOME%7D%2FtempHashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would produce something like:

`currentname=newname`

In file `tempHashes` in wherever PROD_HOME environment or script variable is pointing to, replacing everything else in that file.

But if that CURRENTFILE or NEWFILENAME variables contain anything like whitespace or globbing characters (*?{}[]), that will not work as intended.

To correct for unwanted globbing always quote the variables:

```
JSON="$CURRENTFILE"="$NEWFILENAME"
echo "$JSON" > "${PROD_HOME}"/tempHashes
```

This will still have challenges depending on the sort of data. Filenames on most Linux filesystems can contain equal (=) signs.

Comment: I don't think enough was covered here so I responded with some details ...

Comment: @user, you should show improved code that will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

To me
1) you aren't using constants so lower case
2) the double equals to me is distasteful to me 
3) Quotes should be around the vars etc..
4) You are talking about file NAMES not variables, please label as such
5) you are passing data from a FILE not a variable.

example:

```
json_data_file="${current_filename}=${new_filename}"
cat "$json_data_file" > "${PROD_HOME}/tempHashes"
```

Update: per instruction I updated the code. correctly I think lol

Comment: `a=b=c` does not set `a` **and** `b` to "c", it sets `a` to be the string "b=c". Equivalent code would be `json_data_file=$(printf  "%s=%s" "$current_filename" "$new_filename")`

Comment: Nevertheless, good advice for lower case varnames and quoting.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks I literally never do that type of thing for this very reason. Thanks for explaining my mistake .